# MVVM community toolkit KeyUp event

Tags: c#, mvvm, community-toolkit-mvvm

Can someone please explain me how to get `KeyUp` event in view model?

I have tried with this:

in my view:

```
<TextBox .....>
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="KeyUp">
      <ei:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding}" MethodName="Search"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
</TextBox>
```

In my view model:

```
[RelayCommand]
private void Search()
{
    // ....
}
```

Thank you.

I and getting errors with message that method with correct signature cannot be found on my view model.

I have tried also with

```
[RelayCommand]
private void Search(KeyEventArgs)

[RelayCommand]
private void Search(EventArgs)

[RelayCommand]
private void Search(object)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a command object through CommunityToolkit's generators.  So instead of a method call you want to invoke that command.  The generators append the word "Command" to the method name when creating a RelayCommand.

```xml
<TextBox Name="searchTextBox" .....>
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="KeyUp" SourceObject="{Binding ElementName=searchTextBox}">
      <ei:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SearchCommand}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
</TextBox>
```

You can also add a CommandParameter as needed if you need to provide something (such as a search string?).  Further [examples are here](https://github.com/microsoft/XamlBehaviorsWpf/blob/master/samples/XAMLBehaviorsSample/XAMLBehaviorsSample/InvokeCommandControl.xaml).